# MOSFET Switch Always On?

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I am having a problem where my MOSFET instantly starts conducting when I connect a power supply. I have the gate signal from an Arduino Nano, which is tied low. I am nearly 100% sure I have the drain and the source wired correctly. I have created somewhat of a rough schematic which I have provided also. The load draws A LOT of current (8A). I'm not sure what is causing this. Any input would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Can you ask a specific question please?

Answer (score 6):

The heater load needs to go between the drain and the +12v positive supply, and a new MOSFET may need to be used.

Connecting the heater in this manner might have led to the MOSFET getting damaged the first time it was used (because it's connected in a common-drain voltage buffer configuration and hence must drop 7-ish volts across the channel when the gate is driven to 5 volts). Even if it were only drawing 5 amps when in this configuration, that's still over 30 watts which probably led to catastrophic overheating of the transistor; That overheating likely caused it to now be short-circuited internally.

Also, be sure to double-check the source and drain pins -- if they are backwards, the body diode of the MOSFET will always conduct.

Comment: I am a little off today, the mosfet needs to be turned upside down. The drain is actually in line with the heater, and the source is connected to the 12v.

Comment: And in that case protective diode conduct.

Comment: @user263983 Small nit: That's not a protective diode. It's a parasitic diode inherent to the structure because the FET body is bonded to source, making the body-drain PN junction act as a diode parallel to the channel. It's not an intentional device nor is it in the right place to protect against many inductive kickback events.

Comment: @nanofarad Is   source and drain not the same polarity in MOSFET?

Comment: @user263983 In a *discrete* three-terminal MOSFET, there is no source/drain symmetry. The source and drain are distinct and do not have the same function/"polarity". A MOSFET fabricated on an integrated circuit is a four-terminal device where the source and drain *can* be symmetric (but need not be, e.g. in cases of LDD, etc)

Comment: @nanofarad Thanks, I got it. But for my opinion, "parasitic" is not correct description. It is just a nature of that structure.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to drive 12V load MOSFET with 5V signal directly. No wonder it doesn't work as expected. Your Vgs is always either -7V (when Arduino pin HIGH) or -12V (Arduino pin LOW), which means MOSFET is always open (conducting). In order for MOSFET to close, you need to pull the Gate to 12V (not exactly, but close to it). For that your R1 actually has to be connecting gate to 12V, not ground. To ground is for N-channels.

But then there is a problem. When it's pulled up to 12V, you can't drive it directly from GPIO, you'll burn the arduino. That's why there is a standard construction:

[image]

Of course, N-MOSFET instead of NPN will work - with proper pulldown on the gate and with no gate-to-gpio resistor or some 100-120ohm - your pulldown to ground and series resistor will form a voltage divider, so make sure they differ by a pair orders of magnitude to ignore that.

So you send out HIGH, the NPN (or NMOS) conducts, so the gate of the PMOS is connected through NMOS to ground, gate of PMOS is then at 0V, drain at 12V, so PMOS conducts.

You send out LOW, NPN/NMOS doesn't conduct, the gate of PMOS has no more connection to ground and it's pulled up via the resistor. Drain is 12V, gate is 12V, so the PMOS doesn't conduct.